# Include all records associated with a record that has been found when search is used in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When trying to search for a record in rails I want to be able to return all records that are associated with that id. For instance, if I search for "John", I want to be able to return all records with the same fk.

Table 1

```
| id | 
------
| 1  |
| 2  |
```

Table 2

```
| id | fk | name  |
-------------------
| 1  | 1  | John  |
| 2  | 1  |  Doe  |
| 3  | 2  | David |
| 4  | 2  | Smith |
```

SQL

Rails code in controller

```
includes(:table2).where('table2.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%").references(:table2)
```

SQL returned

```
SELECT FROM `table1` LEFT OUTER JOIN `table2` ON `table2`.`fk` = `table1`.`id` WHERE (table2.name LIKE '%John%') AND `table1`.`id` IN (1)
```

This only returns the row where the search is found. How would I return the record with same fk?

table1 uses `has_many :table2` and table2 uses `belongs_to :table1`

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

index.html.erb just contains a form that submits the input to the controller and the controller runs the query and returns the result.

Expected input: **John**

Expected result:

```
| id | fk | name |
------------------
| 1  | 1  | John |
| 2  | 1  | Doe  |
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(categories_path, method: :get, :enforce_utf8 => false, id: "search-input") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <button type="submit"></button>
<% end %>
```

categories_controller.rb

```
def index
  @categories = Category.search(params[:search])
end

def Category.search(search)
  includes(:category_type).where('category_type.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%").references(:category_type)
end
```

Comment: If you just want all rows where the foreign key matches, what is the "search" logic for? Just use `table1.table2s` to get all `table2` records for a given `table1`.

Comment: @meagar in the front end I have a search box where the user can search for names. The search logic is used to returned the matching records with the ones that are associated through the foreign key

Comment: as far as I understand it, he wants to search for a query in `name`, and then return all the records that either have that name, or share the same `fk`. So for `John`, the result would be `Table1.find(1).table2s`

Comment: Please include an example of your expected inputs and output, and include *real* code. The only sample of Ruby code in your question is incomplete. What is `includes` being chained off of?

Comment: I'm still not clear what you're asking here. What is the expected output, a list of `Category` objects, or a list of `CategoryType` objects? A `where` on `Category` cannot return a list of `CategoryType` objects, assuming you're `table2` is actually meant to represent `CategoryTypes` and `table1` is meant to represent `Category`.

Comment: Worst table naming ever! But anyway, once you get your first @record like "John" you could do:   records = Table2.where(id: @record.table1.fk)

Comment: @meagar When I use where in Category, it searches on CategoryTypes and returns the id of Category and the record that was found in CategoryTypes. However, I also want to return the records that contain the same fk of the CategoryTypes record that was found.

Comment: @bkunzi01 is it possible to return everything at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing a query that returns all of the records for the main table and then using their ids to return the records from the second table. I am thinking that may be another way to get all the results at once, but for now this will do.

```
@records = joins(:category_typed).select('categories.id').where('category_types.name LIKE ?, "%#{search}%")
where(id: @records.ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
CategoryType.where(fk: CategoryType.where('category_types.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%").select(:fk))
```

This will generate the following sudo sql

```
SELECT 
   category_types.*
FROM 
   category_types
WHERE 
   category_types.fk IN (
     SELECT 
        category_types.fk 
     FROM  
        category_types
     WHERE 
        category_types.name LIKE '%JOHN%'
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, not sure this will work as I am in Category and I still want the results from the main table.